# ssis moving data from one database to another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis

I am new to SSIS, I want to pull data from one database to another database.
for example: I have table tb1 it has 5 rows and by using data flow mask move a copy of the table to another database. If first database is inserted with another 5 rows later I run the data flow mask destination database table the inserted record will be added but the existing first 5 rows are duplicating.
My requirement is after first 5 rows are copied to new database table and later after adding second 5 records should be added instead of first 5 records duplicating.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to handle this. The easy way is to use bulk load. For this, you start your control flow (not data flow) with a Execute SQL Statement task that will truncate your destination table. So every time you run your package, the destination table will be truncated and you end up loading whatever in the source table. 
The other approach is to use incremental loading. Here you have many possibilities. Check out this link for more details [Best way for incremental load in ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217134/best-way-for-incremental-load-in-ssis)