# Moving specific data from one database to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is for SQL Server. I have tables `Product` (`product_id` pk) and `Customers` (`cust_id` pk). And a few other tables that have the above as foreign key.

I need to come up with a good set of INSERT statements that can move rows from the tables above, for a specific Product from one database to another. Is there a good tool that can do this?

The twist is also that the different databases have different ids for products and customers - so inserts should first look up the ids based on something else like product name and customer name (assuming there are no duplicates).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30009962/ssis-moving-data-from-one-database-to-another-database

your best bet is to use SSIS for this, and this question has been answered several times on stack overflow. the general direction is in that topic. you will just have to create your own dataflow.

Comment: What are you using the `Other Database` for? I don't think it's a good idea to have different `Keys` for the same products / customers between the databases. You may want to consider replication.

Comment: ttallierchio, it seems like there is still no generic solution. I am thinking - give a tool a product name in the product table - it should then browse the entire database looking for all foreign key references to this product entry (and continue searching recursively) thereby figuring out all the rows that needs to be exported and build an intermediate XML or Script that can then be imported into another database.

Comment: WEI_DBA, Product/Customers is actually a bad example. Consider having to define a "new business process or workflow" in your application. You want to define it first in the QA DB, get it tested and then move that into PROD.

Answer (score 0):

If the databases are within the same server, you may use the following assuming they have the same table structure

```
USE [TESTDB]

SELECT *
  INTO #values
  FROM producttbl

USE [OTHERDB]

INSERT INTO tbl_product
SELECT *
  FROM #values
```

> The twist is also that the different databases have different ids for
>   products and customers - so inserts should first look up the ids based
>   on something else like product name and customer name (assuming there
>   are no duplicates).

For this, you have to create an SQL statement with conditions to lookup for those specific records